# Is temperature an extensive property, like density?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, definition

I was thinking about it some time ago, and now that I've discovered this site I would like to ask it here because I couldn't work it out then.

I know that the higher temperature the air in my room has, the more energy the molecules have. But temperature isn't energy because otherwise we'd be measuring temperature in joules, and we don't. And then temperature would depend on the number of molecules in the room, and that doesn't make any sense. So what I thought temperature had to be was the total energy that the molecules in the room have divided by something, for example the number of molecules or the volume of the room. If it was the latter, then temperature would be exactly like density, only with energy instead of mass. But in any case, I went to Wikipedia and tried to see if I could understand what they said about temperature. I didn't understand too much, but I saw that they used something called entropy to define temperature. I couldn't understand the article on entropy at all, but I think it means my thinking must have been incorrect because otherwise they would mention something simple like this in the article. Could you please explain it to me?

EDIT: Here's why I thought it should be the total energy divided by the volume rather than by the number of particles: because if we divided energy by a number, it would still be energy, and we measure energy in joules, not kelvins.

Comment: Actually, you do hear physicists talk about "a temperature of 0.01eV" or "an energy of 5000K". The conversion factor is the Boltzmann constant: $k_B T$ has units of energy. This is similar to $E = m c^2$ (and again, phrases like "a mass of 0.511eV" are very common). The difference between these two situation is that $k_b T$ is simply a _characteristic energy scale_ of your system - _most_ of the molecules in a gas have an energy of _about_ $k_b T$ - while $E = m c^2$ is an exact equivalence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temperature is related to average energy per degree of freedom via the [equipartition theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem). For example, as the kinetic energy is quadratic in the velocity and corresponds to three degrees of freedom (the three spatial directions), on average each molecule will have a kinetic energy of $\frac32k_BT$ where $k_B$ is the [Boltzmann constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant).

This means that temperature and energy are indeed intimately related (temperature can be considered a measure of average energy) and thus there are so-called [*natural* systems of units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Systems_of_natural_units) which set $k_B=1$. This means that temperature will have the same unit as energy, eg [electron volt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt) in case of particle physics.

While the equipartition theorem probably provides the most intuitive visualization of temperature, it also has its problems: As Arnold Neumaier points out, it only holds under specific assumptions and in particular breaks down in case of [non-ergodic systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_hypothesis) or in cases where continuity is no longer a good approximation for quantized energy levels.

An example of such a system would be a non-atomic gas, which adds quantized internal degrees of freedom to the mix. The [heat capacity of diatomic gases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Diatomic_gas) provides a good illustration for this as it can be derived classically via the equipartition theorem. A reasonably good explanation of the measurements is that 'quantum mechanical' degrees of freedom do not contribute at low temperatures and start approching the classical contribution as temperature increases. Rotational degrees of freedom contribute almost fully at room temperature, whereas the vibrational degrees of freedom only contribute for heavier molecules as the spacing of the vibrational energy levels depends on the reduced mass of the system.

Comment: Everyone knows that room temperature is about 1/40 eV, right?

Comment: Note that this is valid for an ideal gas only!

Comment: @Arnold: that would be news to me - note that I'm only talking about *kinetic* energy, so this should be valid for any non-relativistic system

Comment: @Christoph: Indeed, Wikipedia says that it holds for all classical ergodic systems, and gives a derivation. But there are many classical systems that are not ergodic.

Comment: @Christoph: I read the whole Wikipedia article. The successful examples are all about ideal cases: ideal gas, ideal solution, ideal crystal, in which the relevant degrees of freedom are independent. At the end of the ''solids'' section they say that the equipartition theorem often breaks down.

Comment: (ctd.) and in the history section, they say that Boltzmann formulated it as ''that the average energy was divided equally among all the independent components of motion''. Once independence is lost, the law seems to be approximate only. This is certainly the case in the quantum domain.

Comment: (ctd.) The ''general formulation'' in Wikipedia is not even invariant under coordinate transformations, hence cannot be unconditionally correct. (It is invariant under orthonormal linear transformations, though.)

Comment: (ctd.) For example, for non-ideal gases, they make the approximation that for each atom, the other atoms are spherically symmetric distributed.

Comment: @Christoph: Now I can give a precise statement: With averages taken over the canonical ensemble, the generally valid formula is $\langle f dH\rangle = k_BT\langle df\rangle$ for any observable $f$ and any derivation $d$. If $H=p^2/2m+V(q)$ then choosing $f=v_j=p_j/m$ and $d=\partial_{p_k}$ gives $\langle v_jv_k\rangle=k_BT\delta_{jk}$; so your form of the equipartition theorem holds exactly for gases of classical monatomic atoms, even when these interact, but not for general molecules, not even in the ideal gas case.

Comment: @Arnold: maybe I'm missing something obvious, but as far as I can see, this still works for arbitrary mixtures of molecules as the center-of-mass velocities of each molecule still occur only in a single quadratic term in the Hamiltonian

Comment: @Christoph: But for molecules, the resulting factors are both different from what you stated, and inconsistent with experiment. See the section on ''diatomic gases'' in the Wikipedia article. So you should qualify your answer with the assumption ''monatomic''.

Comment: I forgot in my formula for the expectation of $v_jv_k$ a factor $1/m$ on the rhs.

Comment: @Arnold: I added two paragraphs to my answer - feel free to complain if you there's something wrong with what I wrote...

Comment: Moreover, rotational and vibrational degrees of freedom must be treated quantum-mechanically to get the constant right. And the factor 3/2 is still based on the monatomic case. I'd replace non-atomic by molecular.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: Ignoring quantum mechanics and relativity, every atom has 3kT/2 kinetic energy--- the equipartition holds for every quadratic term in H, and the momentum is quadratic. So it only fails for QM and relativity, not in the other cases you say.

Comment: @RonMaimon: You are right, but Chrisoph was claiming a 3kT/2 kinetic energy for each molecule. And in order that the classically computed total kinetic energy agrees with experiment, one needs to restrict to the monatomic case.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: True, but you save the result if you consider the kinetic energy of the center of mass only, which is appropriate in the case where all rotation and vibration is highly quantum (I'm sure you know all this, I just want to make sure it's clear to others).

Comment: @RonMaimon: I did the classical computation, and got a different factor for the center of mass kinetic energy, based on the full Hamiltonian. Whereas if you take the reduced Hamiltonian for the center of mass motion, you need to approximate the potential by a mean potential depending only on the distance between the center of masses, which is one of the approximations I had mentioned. And then one still gets the wrong factor 3/2 since the quantum rotation/vibration degrees are not accounted for correctly. The Wikipedia articvle gives details.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: I don't care what Wiki says, this is incorrect. The center of mass degree of freedom separates from the relative degree of freedom, and the center of mass is quadratic and you get the _correct_ factor 3/2 for the center of mass contribution, plus an additional complicated contribution for the internal energy, which becomes constant in the highly quantum limit. There are no complications--- it's always CM KE for a molecule is 3/2 kT classically nonrelativistically.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Above I derived the formula $\langle v_j v_k\rangle= k_BT\delta{jk}/m_k$, which holds rigorously for the components $v_j$ of any classical system. From this one can calculate exactly the classical value of the center of mass kinetic energy, and it is $3/2 k_BT$ only when the moloecule is an atom. On the other hand, mixing classical and quantum reasoning makes the result approximate, whatever it is.

Answer (score 2):

In equilibrium, temperature and energy are rigorously related by the first law of thermodynamics.

For one mole of a simple system (chemically homogeneous matter), the first law relates for arbitrary reversible processes the infinitesimal changes $dU$, $dS$, and $dV$ of the internal energy $U$, the entropy $S$ (a measure of microscopic complexity), and the volume $V$, respectively, by the differential equation $dU=TdS-PdV$, where the temperature $T$ and the pressure $P$ appear as factors.

The term $TdS$ is the infinitesimal amount of heat generated or absorbed by the process, which gives some intuitive meaning for entropy as a suitably normalized measure of heat. The term $PdV$ is the infinitesimal amount of mechanical work done by or on the system.

Thus temperature is an ''intensive'' quantity analogous to the pressure. Equilibrium is characterized by constancy of the intensive quantities. Just as pressure differences cause mechanical motion, so temperature differences cause heat flow.

In statistical mechanics, one learns how to express $U$ as a function $U=U(S,V)$ of $S$ and $V$ that depends on the microscopic structure of the material. Keeping $V$ constant (no mechanical work done), the first law implies $T=\partial U(S,V)/\partial S$; keeping $S$ constant (no heat exchange), the first law implies $P=\partial U(S,V)/\partial V$.

For an ideal gas, exact formulas can be derived, leading to the ideal gas law, which say that $PV/T$ is a universal constant $R$ (independent of the composition of the gas).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a huge number of particles, each one is characterized by its energy and velocity. The number is so great that one can not access the speed or energy of a test particle. Physicists have devised a mean to gain some information about this set of particles. They do average position, mass, momentum, energy, ... But to effectively compute this average one needs to know how many particles do have a specific energy. It is the same situation when you compute the average of your marks at school. You need to know how many tests you have got A, B, c, etc.. There is a function, called distribution function which precisely tells us how many particles do have a specific velocity. When the system is in equilibruium, this function depends on a parameter that can be identified with the temperature T. For equilibrium, the macroscopic temperature coincides with the average kinetic energy of a particle. Out of equilibrium temperature may not be unique or even defined.
o you get it right  for the most common case. For the unit, temperature at the microscopic scale always appears combined with kb, the Boltzmann constant, and is often given in eV (1 ev=1.6 10^-19 J)